# onTimer not working as intended - Vector CANoe

Tags: timer, canoe

I am using a DEMO version of Vector CANoe 15.1 and for now, I've managed to create two nodes and two panels. I've created some buttons with which I can control some LEDs. The idea is that I want to use timers so that when I press a button, my LED is blinking with a frequency of 1Hz(1sec). I managed to make it work in 3 out of 5 IGNITION States, but not in the other 2, even if I used the same code. Maybe if I show you my code you can understand me better.

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{
  
}

variables
{
  msTimer MainCyclic;
  msTimer TurnLeftCyclic;
  msTimer TurnRightCyclic;
  msTimer HazardCyclic;
  int ignition;
  int hazardWarning;
  int turnlights;
  int flag1;
  int flag2;
  int flag3;
  byte byte0;
}

on preStart
{
  flag1=0;
  flag2=0;
  flag3=0;
}

on start
{
  setTimer(MainCyclic,50);
//  setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
//  setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
//  setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
}

on timer MainCyclic
{
  setTimer(MainCyclic,50);
  fMain();
}

on timer TurnLeftCyclic
{
  setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
  if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
  else
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
}

on timer TurnRightCyclic
{
  setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
  if (@IPC::RightSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
  }
  else
  {
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
  }
}

on timer HazardCyclic
{
  setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
  if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 1 && @IPC::RightSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
  else if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 0 && @IPC::RightSignal == 0)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
  }
}

on message ExternalLights
  {
    byte0=this.byte(0);
    if (byte0 == 0x0)
    {
      turnlights=0;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x1)
    {
      turnlights=1;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x2)
    {
      turnlights=2;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x4)
    {
      turnlights=0;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x5)
    {
      turnlights=1;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x6)
    {
      turnlights=2;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
  }

on message IGN
  {
    byte0=this.byte(0);
    if (byte0 == 0x0)
      ignition=0;
    if (byte0 == 0x1)
      ignition=1;
    if (byte0 == 0x2)
      ignition=2;
    if (byte0 == 0x3)
      ignition=3;
    if (byte0 == 0x4)
      ignition=4;
  }

void fMain()
{
  if (ignition == 0 || ignition == 1)
  {
     if (turnlights == 0 || turnlights == 1 || turnlights == 2)
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
        @IPC::RightSignal=0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
     }
     if (hazardWarning == 1 && flag3==0)
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
        @IPC::RightSignal=1;
        setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=1;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
     }
     else
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
        @IPC::RightSignal=0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
     }
  }
  else if (ignition == 2 || ignition == 3)
  {
    if (hazardWarning == 0) 
    {
      if (turnlights == 0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 0;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    
      else if (turnlights == 1 && flag1==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 1;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 0;
        setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
        flag1=1;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    
      else if (turnlights == 2 && flag2==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 0;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 1;
        setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=1;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    }    
      else if (hazardWarning==1 && flag3==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 1;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 1;
        setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=1;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
      }
  }
  else if (ignition == 4 && flag3==0)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
    setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
    flag1=0;
    flag2=0;
    flag3=1;
    cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
    cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
  }
}
```

When ignition=0 or 1, should only work as hazardLights(both left and right blinking in the same time). The problem is that when I press the HazardSwitch, LEDs turn ON, but not blinking. I will attach a photo that contains a graphic. For the first seconds, is how this should work(as it works in ignition=2 or 3 or 4) and after that you can see how it works when ignition=0 or 1.

[My panels + graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMY52.png)

Answer (score 0):

I`ve found the problem. Conditions for Ignition 0 or 1 were not set correctly and flag3 was reseted too many times so that my HazardCyclic timer was turning on and off as long as my switch was 0x1. Here is the code now:

```
includes
{
  
}

variables
{
  msTimer MainCyclic;
  msTimer TurnLeftCyclic;
  msTimer TurnRightCyclic;
  msTimer HazardCyclic;
  int ignition;
  int hazardWarning;
  int turnlights;
  int flag1;
  int flag2;
  int flag3;
  byte byte0;
}

on preStart
{
  flag1=0;
  flag2=0;
  flag3=0;
}

on start
{
  setTimer(MainCyclic,50);
//  setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
//  setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
//  setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
}

on timer MainCyclic
{
  setTimer(MainCyclic,50);
  fMain();
}

on timer TurnLeftCyclic
{
  setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
  if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
  else
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
}

on timer TurnRightCyclic
{
  setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
  if (@IPC::RightSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
  }
  else
  {
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
  }
}

on timer HazardCyclic
{
  setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
  if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 1 && @IPC::RightSignal == 1)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
    @IPC::RightSignal=0;
  }
  else if (@IPC::LeftSignal == 0 && @IPC::RightSignal == 0)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
  }
}

on message ExternalLights
  {
    byte0=this.byte(0);
    if (byte0 == 0x0)
    {
      turnlights=0;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x1)
    {
      turnlights=1;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x2)
    {
      turnlights=2;
      hazardWarning=0;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x4)
    {
      turnlights=0;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x5)
    {
      turnlights=1;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
    if (byte0 == 0x6)
    {
      turnlights=2;
      hazardWarning=1;
    }
  }

on message IGN
  {
    byte0=this.byte(0);
    if (byte0 == 0x0)
      ignition=0;
    if (byte0 == 0x1)
      ignition=1;
    if (byte0 == 0x2)
      ignition=2;
    if (byte0 == 0x3)
      ignition=3;
    if (byte0 == 0x4)
      ignition=4;
  }

void fMain()
{
  if (ignition == 0 || ignition == 1)
  {
     if ((turnlights == 0 || turnlights == 1 || turnlights == 2) && (hazardWarning == 0))
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
        @IPC::RightSignal=0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
     }
     if (hazardWarning == 1 && flag3==0)
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
        @IPC::RightSignal=1;
        setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=1;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
     }
     else if(hazardWarning == 0)
     {
        @IPC::LeftSignal=0;
        @IPC::RightSignal=0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
     }
  }
  else if (ignition == 2 || ignition == 3)
  {
    if (hazardWarning == 0) 
    {
      if (turnlights == 0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 0;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 0;
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    
      else if (turnlights == 1 && flag1==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 1;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 0;
        setTimer(TurnLeftCyclic,1500);
        flag1=1;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    
      else if (turnlights == 2 && flag2==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 0;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 1;
        setTimer(TurnRightCyclic,1500);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=1;
        flag3=0;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(HazardCyclic);
      }
    }    
      else if (hazardWarning==1 && flag3==0)
      {
        @IPC::LeftSignal = 1;
        @IPC::RightSignal = 1;
        setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
        flag1=0;
        flag2=0;
        flag3=1;
        cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
        cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
      }
  }
  else if (ignition == 4 && flag3==0)
  {
    @IPC::LeftSignal=1;
    @IPC::RightSignal=1;
    setTimer(HazardCyclic,1000);
    flag1=0;
    flag2=0;
    flag3=1;
    cancelTimer(TurnLeftCyclic);
    cancelTimer(TurnRightCyclic);
  }
}
```

Thank you!